# Call Facebook Plugin onclick

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, plugins

I have a Facebook Send Button plugin and i would like to know if there's any way to switch the FB button by a text?

I was trying to hide the FB DIV and add a

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('share').click(); return false;" />Share</a>

<div  id="share" class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.website.com" data-colorscheme="light" style="z-index:-9999"></div>
```

But nothing happens! Any Suggestion?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: I want to switch the standard fb plugin button to a text, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

For hiding a div, you have to use "display".

Example :

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('share').style.display = 'none'; return false;" />Share</a>
<div id="share" class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.website.com" data-colorscheme="light" style="z-index:-9999">coucou</div>
```

Comment: The div is already hidded, i want to find a solution to call the div functionality!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your facebook plugin works, but to simply replace the contents of a div with text you would do this:

```
document.getElementById("share").innerHTML = "Your Text Here";
```